# How to solve $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty}}{\frac{1 - e^{\frac{-1}{x + 1}}}{1 - e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to solve: $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty}}{\frac{1 - e^{\frac{-1}{x + 1}}}{1 - e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}}$?

I know it's equal to 1. But how to do it rigorously? I've tried to use substitution $y = \frac{-1}{x}$ but then $\frac{-1}{x + 1}$ becomes $\frac{y}{1 - y}$ so it looks like this doesn't help.

Hints are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to use L'Hopital?

Comment: @bb_823 yes, anything l'Hopital, Taylor. But when used l'Hopital I've made it more complicated it seems, but I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**$$\frac{1-\exp(-\frac 1{x+1})}{1-\exp(-\frac 1x)}=\frac{\frac{1-\exp(-\frac 1{x+1})}{\frac {-1}{x+1}}}{\frac{1-\exp(-\frac 1x)}{\frac {-1}x}}\cdot\frac x{x+1}$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}h=1$$

Comment: Yes, looks legit. So basically solving three limits separately. Which all of them result in 1. Then applying subsitution for (-1)/(x + 1) for first limit, (-1)/x for second limit  and then use l'Hopital. Then third is obviously 1. Thanks!

Comment: @meerkat: Yes, that's correct, but this method uses only basic properties of limits and allows you to avoid L'Hopital/Taylor/etc entirely. The limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}h=1$ is a standard result which can be derived from first principles: note that it is the definition of the derivative of $e^x$ evaluated at $x=0$; and $\frac x{x+1}=\frac 1{1+1/x}$ tends to $\frac 1{1+0}=1$ when $x\to\infty$

Answer (score 3):

By Taylor's formula,
$$e^{-1/(1+x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(1+x)^n}=1-\frac{1}{1+x}+O((1+x)^{-2})$$
by Taylor's formula,
$$e^{-\frac{1}{x}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!x^n}=1-\frac{1}{x}+O(x^{-2})$$
both as $x\to\infty$, hence,
$$\frac{1-e^{-1/(1+x)}}{1-e^{-1/x}}\sim\frac{1/(1+x)}{1/x}=\frac{x}{1+x}$$
as $x\to\infty$. Thus the limt is,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{1+x}=1.$$